# Flutter inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() method

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

Let's say I have two screen. ScreenOne and ScreenTwo.
I have a button in ScreenOne that when I press, it goes to ScreenTwo (Navigator.push). so far so good.

Also I have a back button in ScreenTwo and my purpose for this button is to go back to the ScreenOne (Navigator.pop). But when I press this button, It gives me this error:

> Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is
>   unsafe. At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no
>   longer stable. To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose()
>   method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling
>   inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies()
>   method.

How should I fix this issue?

Comment: can you paste your code here ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message while trying to pop a dialog from another class than the one where the dialog was called. I solved it by calling the Navigator.pop function from the class where the dialog was called.

Sorry if this doesn't solve your issue. Your situation may be different.